# Linked List ques

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

My doubt is when I make A.next=None, Shouldnt kam variable also store None? Why is still pointing to Node 6?

```
class Node:

  def __init__(self, data):   # data -> value stored in node
      self.data = data
      self.next = None



a=Node(5)
b=Node(6)
c=Node(7)
d=Node(8)
a.next=b 
b.next=c 
c.next=d 
kam=a.next
a.next=None


while kam is not None:
    print(kam.data)
    kam=kam.next
```

Comment: Imagine if you wrote `kam = a + 1` with `a` being 100 at the time - `kam` would be set to 101, right? Now if you assigned `a = 1000`, would you expect `kam` to magically update to 1001, or to remain at 101?

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you make `next` attribute of `a` instance None, not `c` node. When Python runs `kam=a.next` what really happens is that `kam` becomes whatever `a.next` value is pointing at. If you later change `a.next` then it's not implied that `kam` will change.

Answer (score 0):

> My doubt is when I make A.next=None, Shouldnt kam variable also store None? Why is still pointing to Node 6?

**No**. Python performs *assignments*. It thus sets `kam` to reference to what `a.next` is referencing *at that moment*. It thus copies the reference. If you later alter that value, that will not reflect on the `kam` itself, since it made a copy of the reference at the moment you assigned it.

So `kam` is referring to `b` since of the moment of assignment, `a.next` was referring to `b`:

```
kam=a.next    # kam = b
a.next=None   # a.next = None
```

Answer (score 0):

No kam is pointing to b. And when you do A.next = None the next pointer of A points to none but kam holds reference to b. Think of them to be exclusive.